# can't mount windows cifs share from ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, mount, ubuntu-18.04, cifs

I'm trying to mount a folder on a Windows 10 host from Ubuntu 18.  Flat wired network, 192.168.1.xxx.
Let's keep things really simple.

On Windows, `net share` shows (among others) the default share name `C$`.  Let's use that instead of a custom one.

From Ubuntu, `smbclient -L 192.168.1.xxx` doesn't even ask for a password.  It just fails after a few seconds with `Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT`.  Even with the `ufw` firewall disabled.

`mount -t cifs //192.168.1.xxx/C\$ /mnt/theora --verbose -o username=yyy` asks for a password, but also fails.  It doesn't matter if the password is right or wrong.  I've flailed around with other `-o foo=bar`'s too.
(`vers=1.0` , `=2.0`, `=3.0` fail; `=1.1` or `version=xxx` fails instantly "invalid argument.")

From a macOS 10.15 host also on that network, `smb://192.168.1.xxx/C$` also fails "There was a problem connecting," although the Mac and the Ubuntu ssh and smb between the two of them just fine.

From another Win10 host, map network drive to `\\192.168.1.xxx\C$` times out "network path not found."

All four hosts ping each other.

What should I do to mount the Windows share?  What might be failing?  Where do I look?  AFAIK Windows isn't even noticing the requests to mount.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Try to provide the version. vers=1.0 or version=1.0. If 1.0 works, you can try a higher version 2.0 or 1.1.